# how to deal with exception in LINQ Select statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ query as follows

```
 m_FOO = rawcollection.Select(p=> p.Split(' ')).Select(p =>
            {
                int thing = 0;

                try
                {
                     thing = CalculationThatCanFail(p[1]);
                }
                catch{}
                return new { Test = p[0], FooThing = thing};
            })
            .GroupBy(p => p.Test)
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, s => s.Select(q => q.FooThing).ToList());
```

So, the CalculationThatCanFail throws sometimes. I don't want to put null in and then filter that out with another Where statement later, and a junk value is equally unacceptable. Does anyone know how to handle this cleanly? Thanks.

EDIT: There's a good reason for the double Select statement. This example was edited for brevity

Answer (score 2):

I'm not clear from question if you mean, you don't want to use `null` for `FooThing` or you don't want to use `null` for the entire anonymously typed object. In any case, would this fit the bill?

```
 m_FOO = rawcollection.Select(p=> p.Split(' ')).Select(p =>
        {
            int thing = 0;

            try
            {
                 thing = CalculationThatCanFail(p[1]);
                 return new { Test = p[0], FooThing = thing};
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        })
        .Where(p => p != null)
        .GroupBy(p => p.Test)
        .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, s => s.Select(q => q.FooThing).ToList());
```

Comment: yeah, I was wondering if there was anyway to avoid the .Where(p => p != null)

Comment: @Steve, Oh okay. I'm not entirely sure, but the only thing I can think of with LINQ would be to use the `ForEach()` extension method, but even then, you'll end up manually constructing a collection/enumerable of some sort, rather than having LINQ build it for you. If I may ask, what is your objection to the `Where` clause?

Answer (score 1):

For these situations I use a Maybe type (similar to [this one](http://abdullin.com/journal/2009/10/6/zen-development-practices-c-maybe-monad.html)) for calculations that may or may not return a value, instead of nulls or junk values. It would look like this:

```
Maybe<int> CalculationThatMayHaveAValue(string x)
{
    try
    {
        return CalculationThatCanFail(x);
    }
    catch
    {
        return Maybe<int>.None;
    }
}

 //...

 var xs = ps.Select(p =>
            {
                Maybe<int> thing = CalculationThatMayHaveAValue(p[1]);
                return new { Test = p[0], FooThing = thing};
            })
            .Where(x => x.FooThing.HasValue);
```